Correlated parameters
If I use a regression model for estimating a time-to-event distribution function with several parameters (such as a Weibull), should I consider that those parameters are correlated when I later perform a probabilistic sensitivity analysis?

If you are asking about the parameters, then the answer depends on what distribution you assume of them.  (This is the Bayesian approach.)  But perhaps you are really trying to ask about the parameter estimates?  If so, the answer depends on your estimation method, on the model, and on the correlation structure of the explanatory variables.  Ultimately it comes down to the appropriate method to compute the variance-covariance matrix of the parameter estimates.  Please give us these details.
